# Linkedin API Connection Issue

Tags: php, javascript, linkedin-api

```
 I am trying to connect with linkedin in the site in chrome browser its showing the error:
```

Blocked a frame with origin "https://platform.linkedin.com" from accessing a frame with origin website. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

Blocked a frame with origin "https://platform.linkedin.com" from accessing a frame with origin website. The frame requesting access set "document.domain" to "linkedin.com", but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set "document.domain" to the same value to allow access.
Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
    api_key: hjltf4pxjaa3
    scope : r_basicprofile,r_fullprofile,r_network,rw_groups,r_emailaddress,w_messages
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: false
    credentials_cookie: true
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function onLinkedInAuth(){
        $.blockUI();
        IN.API.Profile("me")
        .fields("id","firstName","lastName","email-address","headline","pictureUrl","location:(name)","industry","positions","current-status","current-status-timestamp","last-modified-timestamp","associations","honors","interests","publications","patents","languages","skills","certifications","educations","courses","three-current-positions","three-past-positions","num-recommenders","recommendations-received","following","date-of-birth","connections","group-memberships")
        .result(displayProfiles);
       }

Please help me out.  Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: You violated Same Origin Policy.

Comment: so how to make it correct..

Comment: Where is your actual API code you're using?

Comment: @Sikander as the error message suggested, make sure the frame and main window have same protocal+host+port combination, or set 'document.domain' of both to a same value.

Comment: M USing Linkedin API in javascript..

Comment: Show your actual code

Comment: @Ian I have pasted the code above and in firefox I am not getting any issue..

Comment: @zihaoyu where i set document.domain value?? but its working in firefox...

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a chrome issue, try using Firefox